# Video hosting with local control

Tags: streaming

I am writing a web application with video lessons in sequence. I want to use a streaming service for high availability and compressing content for different viewports. I would like the user to watch a video to unlock the next one. And I would like to monitor the number of views to know when to release the next one. And I would also like to keep the option of releasing the video publicly with those views counting toward the total number of views.

I read about [OAuth on Vimeo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642980/view-vimeo-private-video-with-an-oauth-token) and think that something like tokens could work, although I'd also need to make an API call to check if a user with a token did finish watching the video.

Does any video streaming service do such a thing?

(Migrated from [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/143435/video-hosting-with-local-control) where the question got no answers in one week.)

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 things you are trying to achieve here:

1. video is private, but becomes public. at [api.video](https://api.video), we have the concept of private videos - where users must have a one time token to watch.  Anyone else using that token will be unable to watch the video.  Once you reach your view threshold, you can make the video public - removing this token behavior.
2. Monitoring the views of each user.  We have a concept of [dynamic metadata](https://api.video/blog/tutorials/dynamic-metadata) - where you can attach session information to each view.  You could track each user's viewing in this way. For example, if you wanted to tag a view as watched by Bob:

   [https://embed.api.video/vod/vi2ZEgTAhfOEeYN7ZnEGsm3i?metadata[user]=bob](https://embed.api.video/vod/vi2ZEgTAhfOEeYN7ZnEGsm3i?metadata%5Buser%5D=bob)

When you load the page of videos - you can query the [video analytics](https://docs.api.video/reference#get_analytics-videos-videoid) for sessions for user=bob.  Each session will list the videoId, and the start/end time of the session.  Your app logic can decide if enough of the video was watched to unlock the next video.